# BigQuery simple query taking a lot of time in a specific database

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I don't know why even when I try to run very simple queries on a specific Big Query dataset they take a lot of time and never execute.
I'm the owner of the project containing the dataset, so it shouldn't be an authorization issue.
Here a simple example of a query not executing on a table of about 76,000 rows (37.4 MB).

```
SELECT Id, COUNT(*) as rows 
FROM [xxxx.yyyy] 
GROUP BY 1
```

Has anyone ever met a similar issue?

Thanks for your help

Comment: More information is needed for anyone to be able to help. For example, providing a job ID would allow a BigQuery engineer to look into the statistics for the query to see what happened.

Comment: Actually queries are never terminated, so I can't find any of their job IDs in Query History

Comment: The project ID is microcred.org:gentle-presence-775, the dataset is called mc_dwh_project. I'm owner of the project, but I can't execute any query, they keep on running and running..

Comment: Do any queries run for you? e.g. `SELECT
  license,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.licenses]
GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY
  2 DESC;`

Comment: Yes, it seems a specific issue of this dataset. I can run queries on the other ones and also the one you sent me

Comment: I realize that this very old project still contains our old domain .com, while now our domain (and our mails) are .com. Could it be somehow related?

Comment: I did not see any problem with this project and dataset, and our troubleshooting probing was able to query the tables. Could you issue the following from command line: bq --project_id=microcred.org:gentle-presence-775 query "select count(*) from [microcred.org:gentle-presence-775:mc_dwh_project.test3]" - this will print jobid right away, and we will be able to investigate further.

Comment: Hi Mosha, thanks. I ran it and I got the following message:                                  Waiting on bqjob_r6b9b7360_00000158312654ec_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
+-----+
| f0_ |
+-----+
|   2 |
+-----+